# Check whether two datasets are statistically different

Tags: statistics

I have two data sets (each with datapoints + standard deviation) and want to check whether they are statistically different. What kind of test would be appropriate?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends. If blue and red samples are randomly obtained, and the same group of items but measured at different times, then paired two-sample t-test applies. If they belong to different groups, the unpaired two-sample t-test is suitable. This decision is based on the assumption that both blue and red samples are normally distributed or can be transformed to a normal distribution by means of a logarithmic transformation. Otherwise, you need to implement Mann-Whitney test. The data values to be used are `Output` percentages given the same `Input` value. Data values should be continuous as in your case.